# Public opinion: Jeremy Corbyn for Prime Minister

Tags: election, united-kingdom, jeremy-corbyn, public-opinion

### What is the public opinion (through polls/surveys) on Jeremy Corbyn since the announcement for the snap election regarding the position of Prime Minister?

---

I have checked:

- [Survation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survation)
- [ComRes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ComRes)
- [YouGov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouGov)
- [ICM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICM_(polling))

But they aim their current polls at Labour, not Jeremy Corbyn with the scope of him being Prime Minister.

**Note**: An answer would align neutral wording (i.e. Both left and right/impartial) on the questions regarding unbias coverage of Jeremy Corbyn, seeing as the UK has the ['most right-wing' press in Europe](https://yougov.co.uk/news/2016/02/07/british-press-most-right-wing-europe/).

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/0/uk-general-election-2017-Polls-odds-tracker/

Comment: This indicates the poll tracker for Labour not Jeremy Corbyn with public opinion of him being Prime Minister. I could easily find poll trackers from right sources and left sources alike, but that doesn't remotely answer the scope of my question.

Comment: It would work if such polls asked the direct question of something along the lines of _"Do you think Jeremy Corbyn would be fit for Prime Minister?"_

Comment: I see. I couldn't find any substantial poll conducted/published by the polling agencies. But there are few polls done by the media. Something like this: http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/jeremy-corbyn-polls-best-prime-minister-labour-theresa-may_uk_58db8a93e4b0546370638770

Comment: I'd take whatever Telegraph has to say about Corbyn with a grain of salt tho. Their writers are very much biased against the man. It would be better to use both Left and Right aligned sources to get a clearer picture.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the Telegraph with Jeremy Corbyn coverage as far as I could throw them, I'll amend my question to indicate this factor when answering the question.

Comment: Given the Brexit controversy and Corbyn's refusal to form a progressive coalition with Greens, LibDem and possibly SNP, I'd not be surprised if many left-aligned voters have turned against him as well. A progressive coalition is after all the last hope of thwarting another Tory gov.

Comment: The same political animosity was predicted throughout the Labour leadership election, but unfortunately that's outside the scope of this question. I'm more than happy to have a discussion, start a chat if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best polling data that I could find specifically in relation to public opinion on Jeremy corbyn

**On April 18th 2017:** (2 days after the snap election was called) [YouGov reported](https://yougov.co.uk/news/2017/03/01/voting-intention-conservatives-42-labour-25-27-28-/) that when asked the question:

Which of the following do you think would make the best Prime Minister?

The public responded:

- 15% - Jeremy Corbyn
- 54% - Theresa May

**On May 30-31 2017:** [YouGov reported](https://yougov.co.uk/news/2017/05/31/voting-intention-conservatives-42-labour-39-30-31-/) that  when asked the question:

Which of the following do you think would makethe best Prime Minister?

The public responded:

- 30% - Jeremy Corbyn
- 43% - Theresa May

There is a detailed breakdown of the answer to this question on every YouGov poll since the EU referendum that can be found [here](http://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/az86euwjv5/YG%20Trackers%20-%20Best%20Prime%20Minister.pdf).

**Analysis:** Public opinion of Corbyn has generally improved since the snap election was called.

Comment: Seems as much as I could find too.

Answer (score 5):

To add to @SleepingGod's answer, a [survey](http://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/hrngg4b5a8/TimesResults_170622_Trackers_W.pdf) released by YouGov on behalf of The Times asked this very question. They compared the dates from 5-7th June to 21st-22nd June and the results are as follows:

### Which of the following do you think would make the best Prime Minister?

**June 5th - June 7th**

- Jeremy Corbyn - 32%
- Theresa May - 43%
- Don't Know - 26%

**June 21st - June 22nd**

- Jeremy Corbyn - 35%
- Theresa May - 34%
- Don't know - 30%

<sup>Sample size: 1670 GB Adults</sup>

<sup>573 Conservatives : 548 Labour : 102 Liberal Democrats</sup>

So it seems public opinion has changed in a positive way for Jeremy Corbyn since the snap election announcement, as for the first time he has overtaken Theresa May.

**Note**: the link I have provided is a PDF file for those who view this through the phone app.